# Multiple goroutines reading from a channel gives wrong data count

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm working on a program where I read a csv file and do below operations:

Full Code is available at:[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/8Mhjco_7RyM)

My CSV file is available at:
[CSV file](https://github.com/westcottian/MyData/blob/master/CSV.csv)

The problem is sometimes I get the correct count for A and B and sometimes I get the wrong count.

I think I'm doing something wrong in Goroutines and channels communication.

When I comment the 2nd goroutine, I get correct result of 1st Goroutine. But when I uncomment 2nd Goroutine, I get incorrect output of Goroutine 1 and 2 both.

Can anyone please explain what wrong I'm doing?

Also when I do go run -race main.go, the result shows me a race condition.

```
func main() {
    input, err := os.Open("CSV.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while opening CSV file.")
        return
    }
    defer input.Close()

    formattedStartDateRange,err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, startDateRange)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    formattedendDateRange,err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, endDateRange)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    reader := csv.NewReader(input)
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    files := make(map[string]chan []string)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    var line []string
    for line, err = reader.Read(); err == nil; line, err = reader.Read() {
        ch, ok := files[line[0]]
        if ok {
            ch <- line
        } else {
            ch = make(chan []string, 8)
            ch <- line
            wg.Add(2) // Must wait for 2 calls to 'done' before moving on

            go func() {
                UserMapMutex.Lock()
                if (findNumberOfBuilds(formattedStartDateRange, formattedendDateRange, ch, wg)) {
                    totalBuildCount++
                }
                UserMapMutex.Unlock()
                wg.Done()
            }()

            go func() {
                UserMapMutex.Lock()
                countUserBuildFrequency(ch, wg)
                UserMapMutex.Unlock()
                wg.Done()
            }()


            files[line[0]] = ch
        }
    }


    if err.Error() != "EOF" {
        fmt.Println("Error while reading CSV file.")
        return
    }
    for _, ch := range files {
        close(ch)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Total Build executed from 1st November to 30th November =", totalBuildCount)
    fmt.Println("Total Build", userBuildFreq["5c00a8f685db9ec46dbc13d7"])
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

Comment: All questions must be complete, without the need to follow links. This means you must include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code and CSV file _in the question_. Providing links to the larger versions is, of course, welcome, but the key is the question must be complete on its own, in case the links die in the future.

Comment: This code is very strange. For each line, you create a goroutine, write a line to a channel, then the goroutines each call a function that uses that channel in some way that is not shown. This a) means that function call may or may not be using the line that was just inserted - you should probably just pass the line instead of using the channel; and b) means that if one of those functions reads a value from the channel, the other won't be able to because that would be twice as many receives as sends; and c) you run two goroutines which are both fully locked so you might as well just use one.

Comment: Correct! The B option mentioned by  you is what I'm doing. I did the same and used only one goroutine.

Comment: But got a doubt, how we would achieve the correct result when we have two goroutines? I understand that if one goroutines reads from channel then other won't be able to read. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, your wg.Done() is being called immediately after you start the goroutine. This means that your WaitGroup is not waiting for the goroutine to finish. Remember that the calling process proceeds when you call a goroutine. Try putting the wg.Done() call *inside* the goroutine, when it's finished doing stuff.

```
go func(wg) {
    // do stuff
    wg.Done
}
```

OR

```
go func(wg) {
    defer wg.Done
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have update the code as you have said in the below link
https://play.golang.org/p/8Mhjco_7RyM

But still it doesn't work out.

When I comment the 2nd goroutine, I get correct result of 1st Goroutine.
But when I uncomment 2nd Goroutine, I get incorrect output of Goroutine 1 and 2 both.

Comment: So I think it is 2nd Goroutine which is creating the mess.

Comment: Do you find anything new?